# Collection in Backbone Model undefined even though instantiated in initialize function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In the Backbone model below I have a nested Backbone collection.

```
var Student = Backbone.Model.extend({
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null,
    initialize: function() {
        this.programCollection = new ProgramCollection({});
    }
});

var ProgramCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ 
    model: Program
});
```

However when trying to add Program objects to collection like so...

```
var testStudent = new Student();
testStudent.get("programCollection").add(new Program());
```

I get the following error:

> Unable to get value of the property 'add': object is null or undefined

Obviously I'm doing something the wrong way since the programCollection is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties of the model instance directly are not the same as `attributes` properties. If you want a model instance to have a collection, which is not data to be stored directly on that student record, set it as a model instance property (as you are doing) but then just access it directly without calling `get`.

```
var testStudent = new Student();
testStudent.programCollection.add(new Program());
```

Comment: I guess I was just confused ;) Is this now a "real" Backbone collection nested in my model or did I manage to put it as plain old javascript?

Comment: It's a real backbone collection instance.